# How to add a space in every 2 char then 4 char inside the string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know how can I add a space in every 2 char then 4 char inside the string in sql.

Example:
If i have the following string:

```
@test = '0458475865'
```

How can I add a space in every 2 char then 4 char inside the string in sql, so that when I select the `@test` then output will be as below:

```
04 5847 5865
```

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative that's available in SQL Server 2012 with a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/80098/5/0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(INT, @test),'## #### ####');
```

The nice thing about this is that you can just change the format string if you need to change the format instead of having to re-write the query.

Here's the tech net [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Comment: I love the new `FORMAT` function; unfortunately it's only available in MS SQL 2012.

Comment: Worth a shot as the sql server version isn't specified.

Comment: Does this preserve leading zeros as asked in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Well the simple way is

```
SELECT LEFT(@test,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@test,3,4) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@test,7,LEN(@test)-6)
```

That should work if just about any SQL software.

Answer (score -1):

Please try it

```
SELECT LEFT(@test,2) + SPACE(1) + SUBSTRING(@test,3,4) + SPACE(1) + SUBSTRING(@test,7,LEN(@test)-6)
```